# How to customize by modifying tab markers in Notepad ++ -

Tags: notepad

I am just started out to use "Notepad ++", after having used "WordPad" and "Office Word" for years, but I notice the tab settings are hidden somewhere in  the menu settings of "Notepad ++". I would like to customize the tab distances by modifying their marker positions.

The tab markers I am referring to are similar to those within "MS WordPad" or - if - the markers are showing - with all "Microsoft Office Word" versions.

I would like to know how to reset distances between two given tab settings. I can appreciate that "Notepad ++" may not display the markers like the two Microsoft products mentioned above.

I look forward to some receiving some advice soonest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To view Tab markers (and other "hidden" characters),

- Select `View` menu.
- Select `Show Symbol` menu item.
- Choose which characters to display.

[image: Display white space and other characters]

BTW, you may also [convert `Tab` characters to a specified number of white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-notepad), which can be useful when formatting for compilers or for other text editors.